# How to test column value is Numeric in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to copy records of a VARCHAR type column to FLOATE type column in same table. Currently I am using some Regular expression to achieve this.And the query I am using is:

```
update ao_invoice_detail t1 set (t1.flex_field21, t1.flex_field22,flex_field23,flex_field24,flex_field25) = (
select
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field1, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field1 end as field1, 
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field2, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field2 end as field2,
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field4, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field4 end as field3,
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field5, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field5 end as field4,
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field8, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field8 end as field5
from
ao_invoice_detail  t2
where
t1.id = t2.id
```

);

The problem with the above query is, it is updating **null** if the corresponding field value is Non-Numeric (overriding the old value of column2). But, my requirement is **IF THE COLUMN1 VALUE IS NUMERIC THEN ONLY UPDATE COLUMN2 OR ELSE DON'T UPDATE**

Can any one please suggest any better way to do this or Do we have any pre-defined function in sql/oracle, so that i can test the data of a column is numeric or alphanumeric?

many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need `else` clauses:

```
select
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field1, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field21 else t1.flex_field21 end as field1, 
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field2, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field22 else t1.flex_field22 end as field2,
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field4, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field24 else t1.flex_field23 end as field3,
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field5, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field25 else t1.flex_field24 end as field4,
 case when regexp_like(t2.flex_field8, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then t2.flex_field28 else t1.flex_field25 end as field5
```

EDIT:

Why are you doing this with a `join`?

```
update ao_invoice_detail 
    set flex_field21 = (case when regexp_like(flex_field1, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then flex_field1 else flex_field21 end),
        flex_field22 = (case when regexp_like(flex_field2, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then flex_field2 else flex_field22 end),
        flex_field23 = (case when regexp_like(flex_field4, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then flex_field4 else flex_field23 end),
        flex_field24 = (case when regexp_like(flex_field5, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then flex_field5 else flex_field24 end),
        flex_field25 = (case when regexp_like(flex_field8, '^-?[[:digit:],.]*$') then flex_field8 else flex_field25 end);
```

Comment: Thanks Linoff for the Quick Solution. But, the above query ll update always.. i mean, even though the COLUMN1 value is Non-numeric it will try to update the COLUMN2 with the old value..which I don't want since I am going o execute this query in huge database. Can we have some function that we can use as a criteria so that we can avoid the unnecessary database hit.

Comment: @Manu . . . That is what a `where` clause is for.  However, updating one field or many in a record is about the same effort.